# donot understand why the answer is comming 6 when i have a loop of 5

Tags: java

```
public class Test implements Runnable {

    static int i;

    public void run() {

        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Test t=new Test();

        for(i=0;i<=5;i++){
            Thread t1=new Thread(t);
            t1.start();
            System.out.println("The main method:"+i);
        }
    }

}
```

the answer i get is :-

```
The main method:0
0
The main method:1
2
The main method:2
The main method:3
The main method:4
5
The main method:5
6
6
6
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT : now I see that `i` is a static variable and is not declared in the loop. The reason it reaches 6 is that it is incremented until the loop's condition `i <= 5` is no longer true, which happens when `i` reaches 6.

Comment: He did post his `Test` class, but it is not indented properly

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the `i<=5`. The 0 being included, `i<5` iterates 5 times (starting from 0 and finishing at 4). If you add `=` you'll "force" the code to stop at 5, iterating 5 + 1 times.

This kind of error is called [off-by-one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) and while it is a frequent error when you start programming it can cause to disastrous bug (see for example [this famous bug in OpenSSL](http://www.freebsd.org/security/advisories/FreeBSD-SA-02:13.openssh.asc))

Answer (score 0):

All threads share a single `static int i;`

The loop in `main` starts threads while i is (still!) 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, but they will execute with some delay. Meanwhile, the main loop advances, and you see some later state of i.

Note that some values are missing, others are duplicate, and there is the mysterious 6, which is the setting when the loop exits, with some of these threads not having reached the println.